# How do I set the default Java installation/runtime (Windows)?

Tags: java, windows, installation, runtime

I'm in the situation where I've installed the JDK, but I can't run applets in browsers (I may not have installed the JRE).

However, when I install the JRE, it clobbers my JDK as the default runtime.  This breaks pretty much everything (Eclipse, Ant) - as they require a server JVM.

There's no `JAVA_HOME` environment variable these days - it just seems to use some registry magic (setting the system path is of no use either).  Previously, I've just uninstalled the JRE after I've used it to restore the JDK.  This time I want to fix it properly.

This also manifests itself with the jre autoupdater - once upon a time, I had a working setup with the JDK and JRE, but it updated and bust everything.

Comment: Curious; I've just got the "Famous Question" badge for this question, and it's only got 5 upvotes? Is this because: A) it's not a good question; B) people accidentally find it when looking for something else; C) This is really popular with the interwebs in general (non SO-users); or D) _(as always)_ "something else"

Comment: [this worked for me where we can by default set the java version run time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71671719/1557383)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is a bit of a pain on Windows. Here's what I do.

Install latest Sun JDK, e.g. **6u11**, in path like `c:\install\jdk\sun\6u11`, then let the installer install public JRE in the default place (`c:\program files\blah`). This will setup your default JRE for the majority of things.

Install older JDKs as necessary, like **5u18** in `c:\install\jdk\sun\5u18`, but don't install the public JREs.

When in development, I have a little batch file that I use to setup a command prompt for each JDK version. Essentially just set `JAVA_HOME=c:\jdk\sun\JDK_DESIRED` and then set `PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%`. This will put the desired JDK first in the path and any secondary tools like Ant or Maven can use the `JAVA_HOME` variable.

The path is important because most public JRE installs put a linked executable at `c:\WINDOWS\System32\java.exe`, which usually *overrides* most other settings.

Comment: The key was to put the desired java/bin as the first thing in the system path.

Comment: i had java_home set and new bin in path, didnt work, I had to install latest jre7 again and that took care of it

Comment: Very good and detailed answer, but missing the new best practice java introduces regarding path location switching. see [stackoverflow.com/questions/27996603](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996603/should-i-add-both-java-home-and-jre-home-in-environmental-variable-path/34733232#34733232).

Comment: @user257319 doesn't seems to me as "the new best practice java introduces", at least there is no reference, this is let say official practice...

Comment: It's funny that you can't just set this in the Java Control Panel... you can set a lot of things there, half of it I don't even understand, but not this.

Answer (score 7):

I have patched the behaviour of my eclipse startup shortcut in the properties dialogue

from

```
"E:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipse.exe"
```

to

```
"E:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipse.exe" -vm "E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin"
```

as described [in the Eclipse documentation](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=eclipse%20launcher&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD4QFjAC&url=http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/launcher_ini.html&ei=tYgTT821O6uTiQe9o4lE&usg=AFQjCNGbNdEYhkI2HTj2PVLG3LIoNkl3Tw&sig2=nk5-P118j3rCEsuU52wf4Q)

It is a patch only, as it depends on the shortcut to fix things...

The alternative is to set the parameter permanently in the eclipse initialisation file.

Answer (score 4):

I just had that problem (Java 1.8 vs. Java 9 on Windows 7) and my findings are:

**short version**

default seems to be (because of Path entry)

```
c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java -version
```

select the version you want (test, use tab completing in cmd, not sure what those numbers represent), I had 2 options, see longer version for details

```
c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath_target_[tab]
```

remove junction/link and link to your version (the one ending with 181743567 in my case for Java 8)

```
rmdir javapath
mklink /D javapath javapath_target_181743567
```

**longer version:**

Reinstall Java 1.8 after Java 9 didn't work. The sequence of installations was jdk1.8.0_74, jdk-9.0.4 and attempt to make Java 8 default with jdk1.8.0_162...

After jdk1.8.0_162 installation I still have

```
java -version
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

What I see in path is

```
Path=...;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;...
```

So I checked what is that and I found it is a junction (link)

```
c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java>dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is DA2F-C2CC

 Directory of c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java

2018-02-07  17:06    <DIR>          .
2018-02-07  17:06    <DIR>          ..
2018-02-08  17:08    <DIR>          .oracle_jre_usage
2017-08-22  11:04    <DIR>          installcache
2018-02-08  17:08    <DIR>          installcache_x64
2018-02-07  17:06    <JUNCTION>     javapath [C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath_target_185258831]
2018-02-07  17:06    <DIR>          javapath_target_181743567
2018-02-07  17:06    <DIR>          javapath_target_185258831
```

Those hashes doesn't ring a bell, but when I checked

```
c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath_target_181743567>.\java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)

c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath_target_185258831>.\java -version
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

so to make Java 8 default again I had to delete the link as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/167076/how-can-i-delete-a-symbolic-link)

```
rmdir javapath
```

and recreate with Java I wanted

```
mklink /D javapath javapath_target_181743567
```

tested:

```
c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java>java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

** update (Java 10) **

With Java 10 it is similar, only javapath is in c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\ which is strange as I installed 64-bit IMHO

```
.\java -version
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2):

After many attempts, I found the junction approach more convenient. This is very similar on how this problem is solved in linux.

Basically it consists of having a *link* between `c:\tools\java\default` and the actual version of java you want to use as default in your system.

---

##How to set it:

1. Download [junction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) and make sure to put it in your PATH
   environment variable
2. Set your environment this way:
   - `PATH` pointing to **ONLY** to this jre `c:\tools\java\default\bin`
   - `JAVA_HOME` pointing to `c:\tools\java\default
3. Store all your jre-s in one folder like (if you do that in your Program FIles folder you may encounter some

   - `C:\tools\Java\JRE_1.6`
   - `C:\tools\Java\JRE_1.7`
   - `C:\tools\Java\JRE_1.8`
4. Open a command prompt and cd to `C:\tools\Java\`
5. Execute `junction default JRE_1.6`

This will create a [junction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) (which is more or less like a symbolic link in linux) between `C:\tools\java\default` and `C:\tools\java\JRE_1.6`

In this way you will always have your default java in `c:\tools\java\default`.

If you then need to change your default java to the 1.8 version you just need to execute

```
junction -d default
junction default JRE_1.8
```

Then you can have batch files to do that without command prompt like
`set_jdk8.bat`
`set_jdk7.bat`

As suggested from @СӏаџԁеМаятіи

##### EDIT: From windows versions >XP , you should use `mklink /J default JRE_1.8`

Comment: That's what I do. But now it's `mklink /J` instead of `junction` for newer version of windows. You can simply use `rmdir` to safely delete the junction (it won't affect the linked folder).

Answer (score 1):

I have several JDK (1.4, 1.5, 1.6) installed in `C:\Java` with their JREs. Then I let Sun update the public JRE in `C:\Program Files\Java`.
Lately there is an improvement, installing in jre6. Previously, there was a different folder per new version (1.5.0_4, 1.5.0_5, etc.), which was taking lot of space

Comment: You might add detail on how to "let Sun update the public JRE ...."  Your reply is not very helpful as it is.

Comment: When you install a JDK on Windows, using their .exe program, in the middle of the installation it asks if it can install the JRE. That's what I meant by "let Sun [now Oracle...] update the public JRE". I always change the default location of the JDK (to a path without spaces, where I put all my Java programs) but always keep the default JRE installation path.

Comment: Your additional explanation is helpful and adds value, @PhiLho.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I simply install all the versions of JDK I need and the latest installed becomes default, so I just reinstall the one I want to be default if necessary.

Comment: That's sad I have to reinstall let say Java 1.8 when I installed Java 9 for testing... As I found later even reinstall did not work for me, check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48690194/384674)

Answer (score 1):

Need to  remove C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath from environment and replace by JAVA_HOME which is works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

an alterable way to run an .jar app is create an .bat cmd for it.
for example, you have jre10 and jre8 installed on your pc,and jre10 is your default jre.
but your jar is specified to work with jre8,following cmd will work:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" -jar JabRef-4.3.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Stacked by this issue and have resolved it in *2020*, in *Windows 10*. I'm using *Java 8 RE* and *14.1 JDK* and it worked well until *Eclipse* upgrade to version *2020-09*. After that I can't run *Eclipse* because it needed to use *Java 11* or newer and it found only *8* version. It was because of order of environment variables of "*Path*":

[image: environment variables setting]

I suppose `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` is path to link to installed JRE exe files (in my case *Java 8*) and the issue was resolved by move down this link after `%JAVA_HOME%`, what leads to *Java 14.1/bin* folder.

[image: EV setting after edit]

It seems that order of environment variables affects order of searched folders while executable file is requested.
Thanks for your comment or better explanation.