# JAVA_HOME not working

Tags: android, java

So I was installing the Android SDK on my new computer (Win 7, 64bit) and I installed the JDK, but when I go to install the SDK it says this

[image: Android SDK]

The enviromental variable is set as well, any ideas?

[image: Enviro variable]

And yes I have tried to go back and then next D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version is your JRE? Is it really located at C:\Program Files\Java, or is it in a subfolder of that (e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0)?

Comment: The accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492937/windows-ignores-java-home-how-to-set-jdk-as-default might shed some light. Is java.exe present in C:\WINDOWS\system32?

Comment: java, javaw and javaws are all present

Comment: what happens when you execute "java -version" from the command prompt?

Comment: Haha, that's good. For future reference, what is your JAVA_HOME set to now?

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere that it might be a bug...The work around was to press ***back*** and then ***Next*** and it should find the JDK.

EDIT: it should **not** be like this: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin` don't include the `\bin` just `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03` then apply and restart your computer.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The value should be something like

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0

Answer (score 1):

The path is this -

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found the answer here:
[Android SDK installation doesn't find JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk)

thx to [simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534294/simon) for the answer:
Use 32-bit JDK not the 64-bit version.