# JMeter.bat runs but doesn't start application

Tags: windows, jmeter

I downloaded JMeter v5.1.1 and tried to run it (double click on 'jmeter.bat') but only Commpand Prompt window starts for a brief while and closes automatically. After that nothing happens
I verified that I have a Java installed with following output

```
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
```

As I read other threads there might be a problem with my Java version OR path system variable so here it is

- User Path var contains: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
- System Path var contains: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
- System Java_Home var: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181`

I verified that Java path is correct and contains java.exe file. Any help? Maybe somebody had similar issue

As of a question asked I paste here jmeter.log

```
2019-04-30 09:48:24,538 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US
2019-04-30 09:48:24,584 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: user.properties
2019-04-30 09:48:24,585 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: system.properties
2019-04-30 09:48:24,598 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2019 The Apache Software Foundation
2019-04-30 09:48:24,598 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 5.1.1 r1855137
2019-04-30 09:48:24,598 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=9
2019-04-30 09:48:24,599 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
2019-04-30 09:48:24,599 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Windows 10
2019-04-30 09:48:24,599 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=amd64
2019-04-30 09:48:24,599 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=10.0
2019-04-30 09:48:24,599 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=Cp1252
2019-04-30 09:48:24,599 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.awt.headless=null
2019-04-30 09:48:24,600 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =3185573888
2019-04-30 09:48:24,600 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =4
2019-04-30 09:48:24,615 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States)
2019-04-30 09:48:24,616 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States)
2019-04-30 09:48:24,616 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=E:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1
2019-04-30 09:48:24,616 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =E:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin
2019-04-30 09:48:24,616 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =E:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin
2019-04-30 09:48:24,619 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: IP: *XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX* Name: *XXXXXXXXXX* FullName: *XXXXXXXXXX*
2019-04-30 09:48:25,583 INFO o.a.j.g.a.LookAndFeelCommand: Installing Darcula LAF
2019-04-30 09:48:25,591 INFO o.a.j.g.a.LookAndFeelCommand: Using look and feel: com.bulenkov.darcula.DarculaLaf [Darcula]
2019-04-30 09:48:25,592 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting LAF to: com.bulenkov.darcula.DarculaLaf
2019-04-30 09:48:25,712 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties
2019-04-30 09:48:27,998 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-04-30 09:48:27,999 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-04-30 09:48:27,999 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-04-30 09:48:28,000 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-04-30 09:48:28,000 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2019-04-30 09:48:28,000 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2019-04-30 09:48:29,188 INFO o.a.j.e.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'keytool'
2019-04-30 09:48:29,189 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file E:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\proxyserver.jks
2019-04-30 09:48:29,490 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='E:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin'
2019-04-30 09:48:30,491 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2019-04-30 09:48:30,492 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2019-04-30 09:48:30,492 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2019-04-30 09:48:30,492 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
```

Comment: Copy pasted your command, output is Java_Home variable specified in the question whitch is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181'. Is the path incorrect? I'm confused because you wrote that I use Java 9 not 8

Comment: In my Java directory I have `jdk1.8.0_181`, `jdk-9`, `jre1.8.0_181`, `jre-9`. I've changed Java_Home system var to `jdk1.8.0_181` & `jdk-9` with no changes in behavior of jmeter.bat

Comment: It doesn't contains any errors or warnings, at least for newby. I copied complete `jmeter.log` into a question as it might be helpfull for you or smb else

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492937/windows-ignores-java-home-how-to-set-jdk-as-default

Comment: Posted thread didn't help, I posted a "dummy" workaround as a temporary answer (**still waiting for proper fix**)

Answer (score 0):

**NOT A FIX, RATHER WORKAROUND**

I started to mess around with files in `jmeter/bin` directory and found out that double click on `ApacheJMeter.jar` instead of trying to use `jmeter.bat` starts the application!

I dunno why and what is happening. I did not make any changes in my system, everything is as it is said in a question. Application starts and works properly (after 1 working day of playing with it, it didn't crush nor I found any misbehavior based on tutorials)