# MobileFirst 8 : change JDK

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using MobileFirst 8 server which is running now with JAVA 7. I need to change JAVA version to 8, I wonder which file should I update.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, how do you know it is running with Java 7...? It works the same way, where it defines to work with Java 7, replace it with Java 8.

Anyway, there is no definition for the used Java version in the MobileFirst Server. It uses whatever your system uses.

So if you installed Java 7 or 8 and defined 7 or 8 to be your default Java version, that is the Java version that the MobileFirst Server will use as well...

I suggest that you will google how to change the default used Java version for your operating system (macOS, Linux, Windows, ...)

[How do I set the default Java installation/runtime (Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551668/how-do-i-set-the-default-java-installation-runtime-windows)
https://superuser.com/questions/650310/switching-between-java-7-and-8-in-os-x

Comment: Yes, I changed my JAVA  system version to JAVA 8, I restart my desktop and everything seems ok now.