# Jenkins requires Java versions [8, 11] but you are running with Java 16 from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1

Tags: jenkins

Trying to install Jenkins but it is showing me this error.

```
Jenkins requires Java versions [8, 11] but you are running 
with Java 16 from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1
```

Please help!

Comment: Seems pretty self-explanatory. Jenkins needs [Java 11 or 8](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/) to run. You have 16. Install 11. And [read the docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/windows/)

Answer (score 8):

1. Download java 11 from below link & install in your system.
   https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html
2. After installing you can find the folder in `C:\Program Files\Java\`

*since I have already installed java 16, I don't want to change the default to 11.*

Run Jenkins as mentioned below:

- open command prompt using **run as administrator** mode
  switch to >>>
  `C:\Windows\system32>` >>
  `cd C:\Program Files\Jenkins`
- Execute this command
  `C:\Program Files\Jenkins>..\Java\jdk-11.0.12\bin\java  -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8080`
- [Jenkin starting after executing above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jgFZ.png)
- Go to HTTP://localhost:8080

You can find admin password from `C:\Users\myuser\\.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword`

- [Go to HTTP://localhost:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPr8r.png)

Comment: Hi, your solution worked perfectly! but the thing is, I need to run those commands every single time to start Jenkins. Is there a way I could permanently change the preferred JDK?

Comment: Yes, you can change the system environment variable "JAVA_HOME" path to your preferred java SDK version path

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was not able to fix it with the above solutions. So, what worked for me is, in environment variables, you can update the path of JAVA_HOME as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321` or the specific path in which you have your java installed. The advantage here is you need not delete the other versions of java. Also remember you need to delete `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` from the existing system variables so that it will consider version 8 as default.
[image: path for JAVA_HOME]    [image: ensure to remove pre-existing javapath from here]

Also need to update the java version pointing in the jenkins to jdk1.8.0_321 in the C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.xml file

```
<executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\bin\java.exe</executable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 batch files using solution provided by

> Bala Subramanium

so u can start Jenkins with one/two click/s

First Bat File is **Jenkins_Initiate.bat** ------>>>>> (use to start Jenkins)

> **cd C:\Program Files\Jenkins**
>
> **..\Java\jdk-11.0.13\bin\java  -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8080**

make sure to have 2 spaces between `java & -jar`

Second Bat File is **Jenkins_Launch.bat** ------>>>>> (use to lauch Jenkins on chrome)

> **start chrome http://localhost:8080**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option —enable-future-java.
You can run jenkins.war on command prompt with the above option. Or you can edit xml file jenkins within your installed Jenkins package to add this option. The following blog discusses this solution. https://medium.com/@rakhi.mundhada1/how-to-run-jenkins-with-java-17-on-a-windows-machine-2a1b1c50960a
Same can be applied to Java 16.